# Magento reindexing a particular single product -Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

My magento store has products around 30000. Everytime i upload/update new product, i have to reindex the whole store which takes very huge time. So basically i would like to have a php script or any method which reindex all the indexes of a particular single product. Is there any defined script/method to achieve?? please help, thank you in advance

Comment: if you switched the `Index Mode` to `Update on Save` will it take the same time ?

Comment: @M.Elwan yes its taking same amount of time